# How is the p-adic norm calculated when using universal witt vectors?

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic, witt-vectors

How is the p-adic norm calculated when using UNIVERSAL WITT VECTORS?

Is the p-adic norm calculated in the familiar way, in the sense that we look to the last digit to the right, and the prime number p associated with that last digit: norm = p to the negative-n?

Or is a more elaborate procedure required, reflecting that we're using universal rather than p-typical p-adic numbers?

Comment: Please add at least one major tag (starting with two letters and a dot).

Comment: OK. The tag nt.number-theory has been added.